# how to open a browser window in jsf, using <h:commandLink>?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

i have a PDF creation action bean in which the PDF is generated and returns to browser..but the problem is that, it opens in a new browser tab..

i had referred:
http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/05/pdf-handling.html

thank you

in jsf

```
 <h:commandLink id="Print"  action="#{Bean.generatePdf}" target="_blank">
                                <h:graphicImage url="../../resources/icons/print.png"/>
  </h:commandLink>
```

bean
pdf generating code provided by balusC

Comment: please post whatever code you have tried.

Comment: if you don't want the PDF to open in a new window, you should remove `target="_blank"`.

Comment: i want it open in a new browser window..but not in new browser tab..

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad... but isn't this a setting that user should configure on his browser?

Comment: actually !! i want do it in javascript using the method window.open()..but in jsf its not working...is any other way to implement this !! or to force user to open in new window..

Comment: well, it seems you need to execute the action via `f:ajax` of `a4j:commandLink` and call `window.open` after ajax request is complete. i can provide an example in a few hours if somebody else doesn't.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/JavascriptOpenNewWindow

Answer (score 0):

in your page you should:

```
<h:commandLink id="Print">
    <h:graphicImage url="../../resources/icons/print.png"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{Bean.generatePdf}" render="scriptPanel" onevent="eventHandler"/>
</h:commandLink>

<h:panelGroup id="scriptPanel">
    <script>
        function eventHandler(event)
        {
            if (event.status == 'success')
            {
                window.open('#{Bean.pdfUrl}');
            }
        }
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and in your bean you should:

```
private String pdfUrl;

public String getPdfUrl()
{
    return pdfUrl;
}

public void generatePdf()
{
    pdfUrl = "/pdfDownload?pdfName=myPdfName"; // set new window url here, and any url parameter you need
}
```

in addition, in your pdf display servlet you should:

```
@WebServlet(name = "PdfServlet", urlPatterns = {"/pdfDownload"})  
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {  

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
        // generate the pdf and send it to response outputstream 
    }  
}
```

Comment: hi..please elaborate about pdfurl ! but here iam just creating pdf and send to outputstream..in this, what should be the urlpdf..my code is:::

 BufferedOutputStream output=genratepdf(facesContext, externalContext, response, object);
output.flush(); facesContext.responseComplete();

Comment: i edited my answer and added a servlet for that purpose.

Comment: actually the genratepdf() which is called in the bean class is a Service class method (spring)and its scope is prototype! Every call must follow this.:..i can get data only from service layer..so  how can i put a servlet and redirect it .